# Where can I get the stock untouched ROM for HTC Desire C?

Tags: htc, stock-rom

I just checked XDA Developers, and I can't find the stock ROM for HTC Desire C. Is it actually discontinued, and is my desire outdated?

Comment: But here I was asking for a link specifically for the desire C as I saw it was apparently discontinued.

Comment: I understand. If we had one "where can I find ROMs" question for every Android device ever, the site would just be like a poorly maintained Google. We'd rather have one question that's useful to everybody than a load of very narrow questions.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new to stackexchange and I didn't have much of an idea about how it works, but thanks for the reply and I will try and ask more appropriate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In xda found [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2220396).

1. First download and install the zip from this thread, this will bring
   you back to stock
2. If you want to flash over your recovery and kernel Do this after you have flashed to zip, if you do it before you cannot flash any zips at all! Follow these command carefully to flash back to stock recovery:

   fastboot flash recovery recovery.img

   fastboot flash boot boot.img

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering about where the download link was, because here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2092147 said it was discontinued.

Comment: Also, do I reboot before I flash the recovery and boot?

Comment: Do I have to do anything with gapps, as well?

Comment: @thePlasm its a stock rom and gapps will be there inside the rom.

Comment: I tried to install the fastboot way and it is getting stuck and boot and now my TWRP is gone! I'm trying to install CWM but it's getting stuck at the htc screen when I'm trying to boot into recovery. Please help!

Comment: I fixed that, but I reflashed Slimbean, can I flash the zip with TWRP, also, should I wipe dalvik, cache and data?